# Copy/paste a range of data as a picture to the left and copy the same range and paste to the right previous paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of data A1:M55 that changes often and I would like to take snap shots for historcial purpsoes of the range and paste as a picture to the right in the worksheet.  Each time the macro is ran it would paste the picture one row paste the last pasted picture, leaving an empty row between each pasted event.  Also would like the first paste to occure in cell AA:1.

A version of the below is what I attempted but based on the results I am using the incorrect approach.

Sub CopyHistory2()

```
Range("A1:M55").Select

Selection.Copy


ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: I would like only the values and the formating to paste.  No formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to combine solutions from multiple questions to get the output I desired.

```
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")

'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

source.Range("A1:M55").Copy

destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```